# API response with this.$route.params.slug

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I'm using vue-router to link through from an 'index' page listing records for a resource, and I have a router-link to take you through to a page for the individual record.  The route works ok, but I'm not able to pull through the API response for just that record.

In the console I get a 404:

> GET http://localhost:8080/this.$route.params.slug 404 (Not Found)

From Devtools, my array is empty

> $route errors:Array[1] 0:Error gin:Array[0]

**router.index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Gins from '@/components/Gins'
import GinsShow from '@/components/GinsShow'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/gins',
      name: 'Gins',
      component: Gins
    },
    {
      path: '/gins/:slug',
      name: 'Gin-Show',
      component: GinsShow
    }
  ]
})
```

**component/GinsShow.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="Gin-Show">
        <div class="container mx-auto pt-16 p-8">
            <h1 class="font-black tracking-wide uppercase mb-8">{{gin.name}}</h1>
                <div class="flex flex-wrap">

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Gin-Show',
    data() {
        return {
            gin: [],
            errors: []
        }
    },


    created() {
        axios.get('this.$route.params.slug')
        .then(response => {
            this.gin = response.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
        })
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string where you shouldn't:

```js
axios.get('this.$route.params.slug')
```

should be

```js
axios.get(this.$route.params.slug)
```

You probably need to construct the URL using the slug parameter, so I expect it would be something like this:

```js
axios.get('/resource/' + this.$route.params.slug)
```

but this depends on your API server.

Comment: Ah yes ok.  So updating to `axios.get('/gins/' + this.$route.params.slug)` has got me a step closer, but still not rendering properly.  My console error is now `GET http://localhost:8080/gins/gunpowder 404 (Not Found)` so I can at least see that the slug is in the URL.

Comment: Now it just sounds like an error on the server side. Is http://localhost:8080/gins/gunpowder a valid route in your API?

Comment: Got it!  `'http://localhost:3000/gins/' + this.$route.params.slug + '.json'` did the trick.